# Poisson Distribution to estimate the probability of consecutive cards in terms of the same "face value" on a Deck

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, card-games

We were given this problem but I'm not sure I understood the term "face value". Does it mean cards with "faces" like Jack, Queen, King? or Does it pertain to the value a card holds like 4 of Spades has the same value with 4 of hearts? Maybe someone else had a similar problem before, please tell me what "face value" means in context of these types of problems.

Here's the original problem:

Suppose you have a well-shuffled deck of 52 cards.  On the average, how many pairs of consecutive cards on the deck have the same face value? Estimate the probability that such a pair exists using Poisson distribution.

I'm also confused with what a well-shuffled deck means. Initially, I am thinking that it suggests that all cards have the same chances of being drawn.

Comment: Face value is the value off the card, e.g.5 or J

Comment: Face value cards are the king, queen, or jack so for example a king of hearts has the same face value as a king of spades.

By well-shuffled they indeed mean that every card has the same probability of being drawn

Comment: Ok. So for this case, the task is to find the probability of drawing consecutive cards with the same face value? (Eg. JoH, JoS, JoD)

Comment: You have $51$ consecutive pairs and you can assign an indicator to each of them, which equal to $1$ when that pair has the same face value. Then the total number of pairs having the same face value will be the sum of these indicators. Then you can take expectation with ease.

Comment: In this problem, "face value" means the rank of the card, for example ace, 2, 3, 4.  It is not limited to the "face cards" Jack, Queen, King.  "Well-shuffled" means that all permutations of the 52 cards are equally likely.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_i$ be an indicator random variable that is equal to $1$ if the card following it has the same face value, and $0$ otherwise

Then $\Bbb P(X_i) = \frac3{51}$

Now the expectation of an indicator r.v. is just  the probability of the event that it indicates, so $\Bbb E(Xi) = \frac 3{51}$

and by linearity of expectation, $\Bbb E(X) =\Bbb E(X_1) + \Bbb E(X_2) +... \Bbb E(X_{51}) = 51\cdot \frac3{51} = 3$

Comment: May I ask where yoou got $\frac{3}{51}$?

Comment: 3 possible pairs for every card? Since there are 4 suits (faces), and 51 since 1 card has been picked?

Comment: Suppose the first card is an ace of spades. Out of the $51$ remaining cards, there are $3$ aces, any of which could be following the ace of spades.